# DataGridTextColumn double click select all

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGridTextColumn but when I click to enter the cell the text now becomes editable, but when I double click on the text it will not select all the text (or just the current word).

```
                    <DataGridTextColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" SortMemberPath="Name" 
                                        Header="Name" 
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" CanUserResize="True" Width="SizeToHeader" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One of solutions, is set style for datagirdcells, that sets MouseDoubleClick event for each unit.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="CellDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And code behind...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Select all text in DataGridCell on DoubleClick
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void CellDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = null;
        TextBox textBox = null;

        cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        textBox = cell.Content as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        textBox.SelectAll();
    }
```